I'm new to Linux. How can I change the way "file names" are showing (see picture)
This is a screenshot of the way files names are showing. I opened the computer this morning and the file names were like that.


This question is similar to: Folders showing lock icon. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Are you sure that you're not being hit with ransomware or some other malware? How do your filenames appear in the terminal with "ls -la"? You don't even have folder names showing in the left pane. Describe what your filenames looked like before this.

Please edit the question and add the version of Ubuntu you are using.

The screenshots I had seen previously that looked like this, had been related to the graphic card driver, as you have indeed indicated by the tags. It might be helpful to update your question and copy-paste into it the output of lspci -k | grep -EA2 'VGA|3D' The needed solution is probably fixing your graphics driver, which might have been borked by a recent update...
